# PHP Prepare Statement for MySQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am a little out of practice with my php and mysql but this particular issue has me scratching my head.

This function works fine.

```
 public function updateGarmentInUse($garid,$inUse){

    $stmt = $this->dbconnect->prepare('UPDATE garments SET garments.inuse = ?,
                            garments.dateupdated = CURDATE() WHERE garments.garmentid = ?');

    $stmt->bind_param("ii",$garInUsePost,$garIdPost);

    $garIdPost = $garid;
    $garInUsePost = $inUse;

    return $stmt->execute();

}
```

However the following function does not work.

```
 public function getOneGarment($garid){

    $stmt = $this->dbconnect->prepare('SELECT garments.garmentid,garments.typeid,garments.sizeid,garments.colorid,garments.timeperiodid,
                            garments.inuse,DATE_FORMAT(garments.dateentered, "%M %d %Y") AS invdate
                        FROM garments WHERE garments.garmentid = ? ');

    $stmt->bind_param("i",$garIdPost);

    $garIdPost = $garid;

    return $stmt->execute();

}
```

I receive Call to a member function fetch_assoc() error on my page which I assume means the query is not properly formed. In order to identify the problem I made the function to read as the following.

```
 public function getOneGarment($garid){

    $garIdPost = $garid;

    return $this->dbconnect->query('SELECT garments.garmentid,garments.typeid,garments.sizeid,garments.colorid,garments.timeperiodid,
                            garments.inuse,DATE_FORMAT(garments.dateentered, "%M %d %Y") AS invdate
                        FROM garments WHERE garments.garmentid ='.$garIdPost.'');

}
```

Since this works I assume that means the value is being passed to the function correctly so I'm at a lost.

Full error I see in my browser.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function  fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example1\views\editGarments.php:20
>   Stack trace:
>        #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example1\index.php(24): include()
>        #1 {main}
>     thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example1\views\editGarments.php on line 20

Comment: Does the first example produce an error?

Comment: That you are Basildon Bond @RiggsFolly!

Comment: The first example works fine with no errors and data is returned successfully.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Actually the First example is an UPDATE and No Data is returned from an UPDATE other then (true or false)

Comment: I really dont see why you do `$garIdPost = $garid;` instead of simply binding the parameter to `$stmt->bind_param("i",$garid);` But that is not an error, just a rather wierd kind of logic

Comment: I have reviewed my other functions and I have an insert that works and of course the update works. As far as the binding I was just following the previous patterns for consistency.

Comment: what error you see?

Comment: The statements that you suggested I add to the top of my script do not seem to be displaying any more info on in my browser.

Comment: I added the full error to the bottom of the question.

Comment: `$this->dbconnect->error` : does this have anything in it?

Comment: $this->dbconnect->error does not have anything.  I placed is in the function before and after the execute statement and no new errors appeared.

Comment: Is there a reason you use variables you assign to /after/ the bind-call, instead of directly binding the method-parameters?

Comment: No, I was just following an example I had laying around.

Comment: The problem is that you're assigning the value *after* you bind it: `$garIdPost = $garid;` - move that to *before* your `stmt->bind` line, and see what happens.

Comment: I moved it with no change. I even tried using the method parameter instead of assigning with the same result.

Comment: You dont have a `fetch_assoc()` in this code, But basically your query has failed and therefore the `execute()` has failed therefore returning FALSE and not a MYSQLI::STMT Object to whereever you ARE running a `fetch_assoc()`